# kafka producer always retry connect

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-sleuth

I'm using spring-cloud-sleuth-stream and spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka sending span to kafka,exception occur in connection.
spring cloud version Edgware.SR1

```
 spring
  cloud:
     stream:
       kafka:
           binder:
               brokers: 192.168.1.177:9092  
               zkNodes: 192.168.1.177:2181
```

192.168.1.177 is my localhost

[Initialize connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMNno.png)

[retry excepetion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYkzR.png)

I cannot understand why `Updated cluster metadata version 2 to Cluster`,and the host is changed to `988fffc614b5`,and how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spring-cloud-sleuth-stream` module is deprecated. Please use the standard `starter-zipkin` with `kafka` on the classpath and proper configuration as described in the documentation.